# Current Path variable in .env file

Tags: python, environment-variables, pipenv

Is there a way to refer to the current directory in a `.env` file?

Trying to point the location of a config file from userprofile, to the current path.  For example,

```
CONFIG_FILE=${USERPROFILE}\.configs\config.cfg
```

I would like to set it to,

```
CONFIG_FILE=${CURRENTPATH}\.configs\config.cfg
```

Comment: maybe using `pwd`

Comment: I'll give that one a shot!, I've tried, `currentpath`, `currentdir`, `currentdirectory`, even `.` (dot)

Comment: `pwd` didn't work

Comment: why dont you put the whole code.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: os.path.abspath(__file__) gives the location of current file from where the code is running.     os.path.dirname( os.path.abspath(__file__ ))  would give the directory where you have placed your .py file . DO not forget to import os

Comment: I am on windows 10

Comment: @spitfiredd  I hope this works

Comment: @spitfiredd  my code will work irrespective of platform

Comment: yeah close the question

Comment: @RoushanSingh I was trying to have it load when I run `pipenv shell|run`, if I can't get that to work I will have to create a load script in my root directory.

Comment: use subprocesses module

Comment: @spitfiredd  by the way i am still not getting what you have asked . seriously

Comment: @RoushanSingh when run your `pipenv shell` is sets environment variables from a `.env` file, I wanted to point a config from from one location to another while I have an active `pipenv shell`

Answer (score 2):

Running my program w/ pipenv on Ubuntu, I'm able to do e.g.:

```sh
SETUP_CFG=${PWD}/setup.cfg
```

And in Python I can do:

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

assert os.environ.get("SETUP_CFG") == (Path.cwd() / "setup.cfg").as_posix()
```